# Texture baking is not in sync

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I applied several materials to my mesh, and when I tried texture baking by reorganizing pressing ctrl + p, the islands are well deployed but as those moves, the texture which is supposed to be shown on the mesh also moves. If I want to keep them still, I can't bake. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Is it for Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: blender internal

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a second UV map (Cycles).

- Use the "+" button in the UV map list: this will create a copy of your original (selected) UV map.
- Arrange the UVs as you need in this second UV map.
- Keep the first UV map as rendering target (the camera button on the right is still active for it)
- Select the second UV map (this selection will indicate this second UV map will be used as bake target, the same way the target image node needs to be selected)
- Bake